# Convert array of 0 and 1 to base36 string

Tags: oracle, plsql

Here is the thing. I have an array of 0 and 1. It is supposed to be a binary string. What i need is to format it to string that contains base36 conversion from that binary.
In other words, i need to do this: array of 1 and 0 -> some kind of binary number -> convert to base36 number -> put it into string.
How to do that?

Thousands of oil, 300 steel and +1 luck to answerers.

Comment: I don't get the bounty offer.  Is that a pop-culture reference?

Comment: How long is the array? Will it fit into an Oracle NUMBER type (38 digits)?

Comment: no. array has about 450 numbers. It is pretty long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Oracle built-in to do this sort of conversion.  In the following example I use two functions witten by [the inestimable Mr Kyte](http://www.oracle.com/technology/oramag/oracle/06-jul/o46asktom.html).  `to_dec()` turns other bases to decimals, and `to_base()` turns decimals into other bases.

The procedure takes an array of ones and zeroes and returns a string of base 36.

```
create or replace type binary_nt as table of number(1,0);
/

create or replace function base2_to_base36 
    (p_onesnzeroes in binary_nt)
    return varchar2
is
    s_b2 varchar2(38);
    n_b10 pls_integer;
    s_b36 varchar2(38);
begin
    for i in 1..p_onesnzeroes.count()
    loop
        s_b2 := s_b2||trim(to_char(p_onesnzeroes(i)));
    end loop;

    n_b10 := to_dec(s_b2, 2);
    s_b36 := to_base(n_b10, 36);

    return s_b36;
end;
/
```

The proof of the pudding and all that ...

```
SQL> set serveroutput on size unlimited
SQL>     declare
  2          bins binary_nt := binary_nt(1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0);
  3          s varchar2(128);
  4      begin
  5          --  10001110 => 142  => 3Y
  6          s :=  base2_to_base36(bins);
  7          dbms_output.put_line(s);
  8      end;
  9      /
3Y

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

**edit**

While I was assembling this sample you posted that your array of zeroes was ~450 entries long.  This routine won't handle anything like that.  It will hurl `ORA-01426: numeric overflow` way before you hit a number of that size.

**edit 2**

If you are happy to gamble with a little imprecision, you could replace the NUMBER variables with BINARY_DOUBLE variables (in both my sample and Tom's functions).  That datatype can handle much bigger numbers.  I cranked it up to `array_count=470`,  which might look like this in base 36 :

```
EKQA1EJ6QB4SC8WOOWKWGGOS4KWWWWCS4WCW4SCWCOSOOS888K4CSC8SWO8OCKC8SSCWCOGK844CKG00SOW8KGS0CC4
```

Comment: Just a question about the comment above:  I'll agree that 10001110(base 2) = 142(base 10), but I believe that 142(base 10) = 3Y(base 36).  Or perhaps I don't understand what "5YCWM" means in this case.

Comment: @BobJarvis - good catch!  I had pasted an earlier version of my sample code instead of the snippet from SQL*PLus which I meant to post.  Now corrected.